# How to test computed properties in Vue.js? Can't mock "data"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, vue.js, vuejs2

I wonder how to test computed properties in `Vue.js`'s unit tests.

I have create a new project via `vue-cli` (`webpack` based).

For example here are my **Component**:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        source: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      removeDuplicates (arr) {
        return [...new Set(arr)]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      types () {
        return this.removeDuplicates(this.source))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've tried to test it like this

```
it('should remove duplicates from array', () => {
  const arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
  const result = FiltersList.computed.types()
  const expectedLength = 3

  expect(result).to.have.length(expectedLength)
})
```

---

**QUESTION** (two problems):

1. `this.source` is `undefined`. How to mock or set value to it? (`FiltersList.data` is a function);
2. Perhaps I don't wan't to call `removeDuplicates` method, but how to mock(stub) this call?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I've found a dumb solution. Dumb but works.

*You have been warned =)*

**The idea**: To use `.call({})` to replace `this` inside that calls:

```
it('should remove duplicates from array', () => {
  const mockSource = {
     source: [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
     getUniq (arr) {
       return FiltersList.methods.removeDuplicates(arr)
     }
  }

  const result = FiltersList.computed.types.call(mockSource)
  const expectedLength = 3

  expect(result).to.have.length(expectedLength)
})
```

So basically you can specify your own `this` with any kind of data.
and call `YourComponent.computed.foo.call(mockSource)`. Same for methods

Comment: @Theo Welcome))

Answer (score -2):

Just change the variable from which depends computed property and expect it.

This is my work example for component computed prop:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Zoom from 'src/components/Zoom'
import $ from 'jquery'

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/**
 * get template for wrapper Vue object make Vue with Zoom component and that template
 * @param wrapperTemplate
 * @returns {Vue$2}
 */
const makeWrapper = (wrapperTemplate = '<div><zoom ref="component"></zoom></div>') => {
  return new Vue({
    template: wrapperTemplate,
    components: {Zoom}
  })
}

const startWrapperWidth = 1093
const startWrapperHeight = 289
const startImageWidth = 1696
const startImageHeight = 949
const padding = 15

/**
 * gets vueWrapper and return component from it
 * @param vueWrapper
 * @param useOffset
 * @returns {'Zoom component'}
 */
const setSizesForComponent = (vueWrapper) => {
  vueWrapper.$mount()
  var cmp = vueWrapper.$refs.component
  var $elWrapper = $(cmp.$el)
  var $elImage = $elWrapper.find(cmp.selectors.image)
  $elWrapper.width(startWrapperWidth)
  $elWrapper.height(startWrapperHeight)
  $elWrapper.css({padding: padding})
  $elImage.width(startImageWidth)
  $elImage.height(startImageHeight)
  cmp.calculateSizesAndProportions()
  return cmp
}
describe('onZoom method (run on mousemove)', () => {
  sinon.spy(Zoom.methods, 'onZoom')
  let vueWrapper = makeWrapper()
  let cmp = setSizesForComponent(vueWrapper)
  let e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
  e.initEvent('mousemove', true, true)
  e.pageX = 150
  e.pageY = 250
  let callsOnZoomBeforeMousemove = Zoom.methods.onZoom.callCount
  cmp.$el.dispatchEvent(e)
  describe('left and top computed props', () => {
    it('left', () => {
      expect(cmp.left).is.equal(-74)
    })
    it('top', () => {
      expect(cmp.top).is.equal(-536)
    })
  })
})
```